# Recieving only the structure of the table using SQL and PHP and put into an Array

Tags: php, sql, data-structures

Is it possible to receive only the structure of the table even if its empty and put the field names in an array. If so which SQL command makes that possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL 5.0 or later, you can get the field names from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table.

Something like

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = <table_name>
```

Here is a [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) to a list of tables in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database.

Comment: +1, The `FROM` clause could be written as `FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and note that <table_name> is a string, for example 'Table1'.

Comment: hmmm cant get it to work :/ can someone give a good example if lets just say my table name is 'vraag'?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle and MySQL, this SQL query will give you the details of the table, including columns and column types:

```
describe table_name
```

This may or may not work in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the link the awnser is for example table 'vraag'

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'vraag'
```